# ContentObserver in not calling onChange() method

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-context

I was just trying to count the number of SMS in my inbox.

When new SMS comes `onChange()` method was not being called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me this works:

```
getContentResolver().registerContentObserver( Uri.parse( "content://mms-sms/" ), false, myObserver );
```

Comment: plz explain me when and how onChange() will trigger,,if possible send me some programs,,,,